# Basic and free variables of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I have:

$$  \begin{bmatrix}
 1& 6 &  0 & 3 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0& 0 &  1 & -4 & 0 & 5\\ 
 0& 0 &  0 & 0 & 1 & 7
\end{bmatrix} $$

Do the basic variables have to be $x_1, x_3, x_5$? Can they be $x_2, x_4, x_6$ instead and you write your general solution in terms of $x_1, x_3, x_5$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a system (if it's totally reduced with Gauss elimination method) with $6$ variables to determine and three equations, so the vector space generated by the solutions of the system has dimension equal to $6-3=3$.
This means that the system has three free parameters. You usually define the last variable, in your case $x_6$, as a free parameter in $\mathbb K$ in order to obtain all the other variables.
If we look at the system you wrote we have:
$$x_5=-7x_6=-7t$$
$$x_4=s\implies x_3=4x_4-5x_6=4s-5t$$
$$x_2=u\implies x_1=-3x_4-6x_2=-3s-6u$$
This is a quite rapid way to extract the variables but in general you can arbitarily define the free parameters.